# SQL Count Total ROWS for an ID

Tags: sql, count

I need to get some information of a SQL Database, I have and a group of ID which I need to count the number of rows and then display the ID and the Number of rows but only if the number of rows is greater than 3.

I already have the following code but I am unable to put the `count(*)` in the where clause.

```
SELECT StaffID, COUNT(*)
FROM StaffAbsence where StartDate > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
GROUP BY StaffID
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `HAVING` clause with your `GROUP BY` statement, e.g.

```
SELECT StaffID, COUNT(*) 
FROM StaffAbsence WHERE StartDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY StaffID HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```

Comment: Ok expanding on this would this work in a nested query? So we got the ID's from the Above Query and then performed another query to get back the Individual rows based on the ID? I will have to go and play and see what I can get.